# How to show a loading state in sveltekit correctly?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to show a spinner in +layout.svelte, while the +page.js is fetching data. With the code below the navigating is not available until all api calls have finished. After the loading I see the console.log.

What ist wrong? How can I show the loading state correctly?

+layout.svelte

```
<script>


  import { navigating } from '$app/stores';

  console.log(navigating)
</script>


  <main>
   
      {#if $navigating}
        <Spinner />
      {:else}
        <slot />
      {/if}
  
  </main>
```

Comment: This seems to happen only if both the layout and page are being loaded at the same time. It is in the docs as [parallel loading](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#parallel-loading). I could not find a way to easily disable that.

Comment: You can try to use `import { page } from '$app/stores';` and test if data is not present yet with `{#if !$page.data}`.

Answer (score 0):

in our application we use the `beforeNavigate` and `afterNavigate` functions on top `+layout.svelte` to display the loading status.

```
import { afterNavigate, beforeNavigate } from '$app/navigation';

let loading = false;

beforeNavigate(() => {
    loading = true;
});

afterNavigate(() => {
    loading = false;
});
```

The `loading` variable could be svelte/store, so you can use it whenever you want.